# Using MySQL to run update on a large table is very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, database-performance

I am using UPDATE to fill in the missing value in m3 by matching m2 to n1, finding the corresponding value in n2, and inserting it into m3. Table mmm has 2.5 million rows, and table nnn has 55,000 rows.

Both of the below queries work, but the problem is performance. Right now, I'm updating mmm in a piecemeal way. I have reduced nnn to its first 10,000 rows. In that case, this partial query completes about 18% of what I want to accomplish after 7 hours. The problem with this approach is I have to do about 10 more lookups in this manner. I know this is a lot of computation, but I figured there was a better way.

Is there any way I can speed this process up? I appreciate the feedback.

**Query #1**

```
UPDATE mmm, nnn
SET mmm.m3 = nnn.n2
WHERE mmm.m2 = nnn.n1
```

**Query #2**

```
UPDATE  mmm a
   INNER JOIN nnn b
      ON b.n1 = a.m2
SET a.m3 = b.n2
WHERE   b.n1 = a.m2
```

**Table mmm (only the combination is unique)**

```
m1            m2             m3
0002-1962     0025117388   
0002-1962     14644418453    
0003-2417     0026708363
```

**Table nnn (n1 is unique)**

```
n1            n2
0025117388    1111-2222 
14644418453   1515-2323
0026708363    1515-2323
```

Database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `mmm` (
  `m1` char(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `m2` varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `m3` char(9) NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `nnn` (
  `n1` varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `n2` char(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: How many records are usually updated after query #1/#2 execution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `EXPLAIN` in front of your query to see how mysql will handle the execution. Without any index to use it must do a full table scan over your 2.5 million rows to select from mmm. Start by specifying your primary keys so mysql can use them as indexes for the queries. You may find you also need to add non-unique index to the m2 column to speed that select.

```
CREATE TABLE `mmm` (
  `m1` varchar(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `m2` varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `m3` varchar(9) NULL DEFAULT '',
  primary key (m1, m2, m3)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `nnn` (
  `n1` varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `n2` varchar(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  primary key (n1)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: I did everything you said, and it worked GREAT. (The creation of a primary key helped, but the important change was the creation of the index in m2.) I was able to update the 2.5 million records in mmm against all 50k records in nnn in less than 20 seconds! Thank you so much. I have never gotten such useful advice.